# Get Audio Power Levels from Currently Playing Music on an iOS Device

Tags: ios, audio, output, fft

I'm aiming to create an audio-visualisation app for iOS. I need to somehow tap into the current audio output from another app (such as Apple's music app, or Spotify) and get the amplitude of the signal for each sample of the music. I will then perform an FFT algorithm on the data to convert it to the frequency-domain and display the data visually.

Is it possible to read this data from the audio output of other apps? If so, what do I need to use to extract this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The iOS security sandbox will prevent the reading of any audio samples from other apps via any public API (unless the playing app was coded to explicitly export audio data via inter-app audio or other similar interface).